# php preg_replace this url

Tags: preg-replace

I want to replace this url, before array gets inserted in mysql table.
I have title description and link in array, and link has too much "junk"

Here is sample of what var_dump($item["link"]); looks like:
["link"]=> string(88) "http://www.hello.com/junk/junk-ju-junkj-junk-jun-ju-junk,-JU-1234"

I would like to get link replaced like this:
["link"]=> string(88) "http://www.hello.com/te/tst?te=1234"

So search everything between "http://www.hello.com" and "very last '-' ...before 1234"
and replace it with "/te/tst?te="

How do I replace this before it gets inserted in mysql table?

Thank you in advance for your expertise and time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you anticipate other top-level domains other than 'com'? Assuming

```
$item['link'] = 'http://www.hello.com/junk/junk-ju-junkj-junk-jun-ju-junk,-JU-1234';
```

You can do

```
$pattern = '/(^http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\.com).*?-(\d+)/';
$replacement = '$1/te/tst?te=$2';
$item['link'] = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $item['link']);
```

You'll get

```
$item['link'] = 'http://www.hello.com/te/tst?te=1234';
```

Comment: Perfect :) Works just like I wanted. Thanks again !